# What are differences between PayPal REST APIs, and Classic NVP/SOAP APIs?

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-nvp

Recently, I implemented the PayPal Commerce Platform

**How it is different from PayPal Adaptive Chained Payments, using Express Checkout?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's an open-ended question. Some essential differences are that PayPal Adaptive Payments is no longer supported for new integrations, so it's not really an option anymore. And PayPal Commerce Platform may not yet have an option for chaining payments to multiple receivers.

Comment: Ohhhk. Thanks. That's helpful.